# Adobe DTM - How to call the variable defined in the page from DTM?

Tags: adobe-analytics

We have page name defined in the website. All page level tracking is defined in the website. Now I am trying to do custom tracking ie event based rule with the help of DTM. With the DTM i have set evars and events and it is working as expected. Now to get the page name i need to call the variable defined in the website from DTM. How can we call the variable pagename from DTM?

Comment: s_code.js and omniture.js are not moved to DTM. We still have it in the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying that you have the page name defined on the site, I presume that you have a data layer implemented.  If this is the case, create a Data Element with a data type of JS Object and under the path define the path where the value for the page name is located.

You can the edit the SiteCatalyst tag and under Pageviews & Content, call the data element from the Page Name field.

You could also do the following under the custom page code in the Adobe Analytics section of the event rule:
s.pageName = _satellite.getVar('page name'); //'page name' is the name used for the data element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this?  If you can share it would be great help.

Comment: Yes I was able to add the data layer and referred http://webanalyticsfordevelopers.com/2014/11/04/data-elements-vs-data-layer/. In case anybody looking for it.